# PDO not inserting into database but has correct values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a basic blog and I've followed the syntax completely of a previous project to insert into a mysql database but this will not add. I echo'd the values to see if it is passing it correctly and it is but when I check my database nothing is added. IS there something wrong that anyone can see with my code? Thank you in advance to anyone who answers regardless if you are able to help or not.

edit: I also checked my database and it is working correctly and is as named, also connect.php works for my login so since the information is the same it should work here.

edit2: Database table is as follows

```
postid int(10) auto_increment 

title    text

author   text

date     date

content  text

tag1     text

tag2     text
```

---

```
<?php

// Make sure the user is logged in
session_name('blog');
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: loginhome.php");
    exit;
}

// Connect to the database and add a message
include("connect.php"); 

$one = $_POST['title'];
$two = $_POST['author'];
$three = $_POST['content'];
$four = $_POST['cat1'];
$five = $_POST['cat2'];
echo $two;


$add_message_query = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO `blogposts`
        (`title`, `author`, `date`, `content`, `tag1`, `tag2`)
    VALUES
        (:title, :author, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, :content, :cat1, :cat2)
    ");

$add_message_query->execute(
    array(
    ':author' => $one,
    ':title' => $two,
    ':content' => $three,
    ':cat1' => $four,
    ':cat2' => $five
    )
);
//go to home to show new post
//header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump($db->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($add_message_query->ErrorInfo())`?

Comment: You do notice that you're inserting `$_POST['title']` as `:author` ?
Also I'd personally prefer `NOW()`  over `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `varchar` over `text` in fields with less than 500 characters, like title and author.

Comment: asfasfsarray(3) { [0]=> string(5) "23000" [1]=> int(1048) [2]=> string(28) "Column 'tag1' cannot be null" } is what is posted when I do var_dump($add_message_query->ErrorInfo())   and i did not see that I switched thank you very much

Comment: @Chris Seems you have no value for `$_POST['cat1']` then. Did you try var_dump() for that too?

Comment: Thank you Thorbear. I mixed up my id and name's in my html on the page before. I appreiciate the help from you all.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` for a better error handling.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php